# pthread how to create many threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

To create one thread, I did like this:

```
void *routine(void *i){....}

pthread_t thread1;
pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, routine, NULL);
```

Now I want to create 100 threads and all of them execute `routine`, do I have to do like below? Is it possible to use a for loop?

```
pthread_t thread1;
pthread_t thread2;
...
pthread_t thread100;

pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, routine, NULL);
pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, routine, NULL);
....
pthread_create(&thread100, NULL, routine, NULL);
```

Comment: Of course.  Did you not try it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an array of threads

```
#define NTHREADS 100
pthread_t th[NTHREADS];
int i;
for (i=0;i<NTHREADS;++i)
    pthread_create(&th[i],...);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just take `pthread_t thread_arr[100];`(array of threads). Work it out as you work with single thread_t variable. Use pthread_arr[1], pthread_arr[2]... as individual variables.